# How to sketch the graph of $\sqrt x+\sqrt y=1$ in order to find the area between it and $x+y=1$?

Tags: definite-integrals, graphing-functions, area

How to manually sketch the graph of $\sqrt x+\sqrt y=1$ in order to find the area bounded by the curves $x+y=1$ and $\sqrt x+\sqrt y=1$ ?

The graph of the first function doesn't seem to any standard graph while the second one is the equation of a straight line . Any suggestions on how to roughly sketch it so that I can find the required area ?

Comment: You can always solve for $y$ here noting that 

$$ \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} = 1 \rightarrow y = 1 - 2 \sqrt{x} +x$$. This is a line that has been shifted by a $\sqrt{x}$ function and corresponds to a rotated parabola of sorts. Now sure how this is helpful to work with though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't require to sketch the graph to find the area.
Find where the teri graphs intersect.
$√x+√y=1$
$x+y+2√xy=1$
But,
$x+y=1$

So$√xy=0$

$x=0$. Or. $y=0$.

So when $x=0,y=1$
                 $y=0,x=1$

$(0,1). (1,0)$ are where they intersect.

Now you can use integration to find the area bounded by the curve and line between points $(1,0) ; (0,1)$ on X axis.

And the difference will give you the area between them.

Comment: Please format your answer to have some success on this site

Comment: @imranfat i am still learning the use of mathjax.

Comment: @ anonymous did you get it?

Answer (score 0):

Take the graph of $x+y=1,$ which is a line thru $(0,1)$ and $(1,0).$ Take a few points $(x,y)$ on this line with $x\in [0,1/2].$ For each of them the points $(x^2,y^2)$ and $(y^2,x^2)$ will lie on the  graph you wish to sketch.  It won't take many points to get a good idea of the shape.

Answer (score 0):

To get an idea on how to sketch the graph, we can implicitly differentiate $\sqrt x+\sqrt y = 1$ to get $y' = -\sqrt\frac y x$ and $y'' = \frac {\sqrt x+\sqrt y} {2x^{\frac 3 2}}$ (note that both $x$ and $y$ fall inside the closed interval $[0,1]$). So, the graph will be a decreasing function from $0$ to $1$ (since $y'\leqslant0\forall x,y$) that is concave up ($y''\geqslant0\forall x,y$). That is as far as we can go regarding sketching the graph.

As for finding the area between the two curves, since the whole graph is above the $x$ axis, we can rewrite the equation as $y = 1+x-2\sqrt x, x\in[0,1]$. So the area bound between the two curves will be (note that the area bounded by $x+y=1$ above the $y$ axis between $[0,1]$ is the area of a perpendicular triangle of side lengths $1$, so its area is $\frac 1 2$) 
$\displaystyle\frac 1 2-\int_0^11+x-2\sqrt xdx=\frac 1 2 -\frac 1 6=\frac 1 3$